# AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'users'

Tags: python, attributeerror, telethon

When I run this code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import AddChatUserRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPhoneContact
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ImportContactsRequest
client = TelegramClient('session_name',
api_id,
api_hash)
client.start()
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone=guest_phone_number, first_name="custom_first_name",  last_name="custom_last_name")
result = client(ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
client(AddChatUserRequest(user_id=result.users[0], fwd_limit=0, chat_id=group_id))
```

it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'users'
```

Help, please(

Comment: Please include the full stack of the error returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it appears the issue is that the client() call returned result and you expected the result variable to have a users item that is an array that you were trying to get the first element of.  You need to check the result object to see what it looks like when its returned to your program.

Comment: result = <coroutine object UserMethods.__call__ at 0xb5cc7588

Comment: If you do a dir(result) it will give you  a list of the attribute names the object has.   This will indicate if it has a particular attribute you can use.  My guess is this time you are not getting  back a users attrbute