# How to solve the error 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'users'?

Tags: python, telethon

I want to [Retrieving all chat members](https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/examples/chats-and-channels.html#checking-a-link-without-joining) using Telethon.

Here is my code:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
from time import sleep
api_id = 134565
api_hash = 'xxxxxx'
client = TelegramClient(None, api_id, api_hash)
 
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
offset = 0
limit = 100
all_participants = []

while True:
    participants = client(GetParticipantsRequest(
        channel, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit,
        hash=0
    ))
    if not participants.users:
        break
    all_participants.extend(participants.users)
    offset += len(participants.users)
Note
```

The code rised the below error:
I try this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826230/attributeerror-coroutine-object-has-no-attribute-users) but it doesn't enough information about the error.

```
<module>
      19         hash=0
      20     ))
 ---> 21     if not participants.users:
      22         break
      23     all_participants.extend(participants.users)
 
 AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'users'
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: You need to provide a more detail error message

Comment: First, you should provide code that is reproducible, for example you are lacking the import for TelegramClient from telethon. Related to what I imagine you want to do, is retrieve the participants in a chat you can do it using this method instead, [get_participants](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html).

Answer (score 0):

Coroutine object in python was used for async program, for details can read
[Coroutines and Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).

In your code, raise an error **'coroutine' object has no attribute 'users'**, maybe caused by you calling an async API but not await it.

You can see an example in office site, the example used async/await
[image]

Comment: It does not work. could you please revised my code with this solution ?